# Adding True / False values to a pandas dataframe from a condition on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'id': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'id': [10, 30, 40, 70]})

print(a)
print(b)

# a
   id
0  10
1  20
2  30
3  40
4  50
5  60
6  70

# b
   id
0  10
1  30
2  40
3  70
```

I am trying to have an extra column in `a` if `id` is present on `b` like so:

```
# a
   id   present
0  10   True
1  20   False
2  30   True
3  40   True
4  50   False
5  60   False
6  70   True
```

What I've tried:

```
a.join(b,rsuffix='a')
# and then thought I'd replace nans with False and values with True
# but it does not return what I expect as it joined row by row

    id  ida
0   10  10.000
1   20  30.000
2   30  40.000
3   40  70.000
4   50  nan
5   60  nan
6   70  nan
```

Then I added:

```
a.join(b,rsuffix='a', on='id')
```

But did not get what I expected as well:

```
    id  ida
0   10  nan
1   20  nan
2   30  nan
3   40  nan
4   50  nan
5   60  nan
6   70  nan
```

I also tried `a['present'] = b['id'].isin(a['id'])` but that returned not what I expect:

```
id  present
0   10  True
1   20  True
2   30  True
3   40  True
4   50  NaN
5   60  NaN
6   70  NaN
```

How can I have an extra column in `a` denoting if `id` is present in b with True / False statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, need test `a['id']` with `b['id']` in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
a['present'] = a['id'].isin(b['id'])
print (a)
   id  present
0  10     True
1  20    False
2  30     True
3  40     True
4  50    False
5  60    False
6  70     True
```

With `merge` is possible use parameter `indicator=True` in left join and test `_merge` column for `both`:

```
a['present'] = a.merge(b, on='id', how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'].eq('both')
print (a)
   id  present
0  10     True
1  20    False
2  30     True
3  40     True
4  50    False
5  60    False
6  70     True
```